# Charset for German uppercase letters

Tags: java, string, file, character-encoding

I try to write to file German symbols but have an issue with uppercase like **Ö**.

Symbols in lowercase are written good. I use ISO_8859_1 charset for my OutputStreamWriter.

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

When I write to file symbol "**Ü**" I expect to see "**Ü**", but I see "**/xC3?**"

Comment: What happens? Please [edit] your question and include a sample input, the expected output and the output you get.

Comment: Have you tried to encode the file in UTF-8? Like switching from `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` to `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`?

Comment: Maybe your file editor does not support German special letters.

Comment: You need to make sure that your file editor/viewer ALSO uses the ISO-8859-1 encoding, currently it isn't

Answer (score 4):

I tried following example and it is working fine:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\output.txt");
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,
                                                                       StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

        outputStreamWriter.write("When it is not possible to use the umlauts (for example, when using a restricted character set) the characters Ä, Ö, Ü, ä, ö, ü should be transcribed as Ae, Oe, Ue, ae, oe, ue respectively, following the earlier postvocalic-e convention; simply using the base vowel (e.g. u instead of ü) would be wrong and misleading. However, such transcription should be avoided if possible, especially with names. Names often exist in different variants, such as \"Müller\" and \"Mueller\", and with such transcriptions in use one could not work out the correct spelling of the name.");

        outputStreamWriter.close();

    }

}
```

**Output:** When it is not possible to use the umlauts (for example, when using a restricted character set) the characters Ä, Ö, Ü, ä, ö, ü should be transcribed as Ae, Oe, Ue, ae, oe, ue respectively, following the earlier postvocalic-e convention; simply using the base vowel (e.g. u instead of ü) would be wrong and misleading. However, such transcription should be avoided if possible, especially with names. Names often exist in different variants, such as "Müller" and "Mueller", and with such transcriptions in use one could not work out the correct spelling of the name.

*Let me know if words are properly encode or not as I can't able to read German.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Java source file (if using String literals) or text input file or (?) is encoded in UTF-8 but the compiler that is reading it is not. In all cases, you must have the Java compiler read Java source files with the character encoding that they were written with. (Actually, that applies to every human or program reading any text file.)

```
javac --help
javac … -encoding UTF-8 …
```

It's probably best to use the same Java source file encoding throughout your project. If your editor/IDE has a project system, configure it for your chosen encoding and it will pass the right encoding to the compiler. UTF-8 is a great choice.

If you are reading the input from somewhere, verify that the code uses the encoding that the file writer used.

---

On the other hand, text files are for experts because they require deciding on a character encoding, communicating the character encoding to readers and every reader using that character encoding. It works okay for some specialized types of text files such as configuration or properties files but not for user-provided/user-consumed files. Some specialized types of text files that are good for data are: JSON and XML.